# Get activity body from activity ID

Tags: getstream-io

How can I use the PHP getstream API to retrieve all the information about an activity from the activity id?

When we add activities we locally store the ID's for them, how could we get the activity body given that activity id **5c23d1be-0dc5-12e6-2080-1000759b484d** using the php API?

Answer (score 1):

One way to retrieve this single activity using the Stream PHP client would be:

```
$options = array("id_lte" => $uuid);
$results = $user_feed_1->getActivities(0, 1, $options);
```

Also, one thing you can do is to set `foreign_id` which can be used as a unique id to retrieve/delete/update an activity:

```
// Remove an activity by its id
$user_feed_1->removeActivity("e561de8f-00f1-11e4-b400-0cc47a024be0");

// Remove activities with foreign_id 'run:1'
$user_feed_1->removeActivity('run:1', true);
```